# Video Source issue with Open Graph Embedding

Tags: facebook, video

I created a test page at:

http://www.gmwebcast.com/test4.html

When I try to embed that into facebook, it gets my player but doesnt load the content.  The player I am using uses the flashvar mediaSuiteURL to pass all the video data to the player.  This includes metadata and the like.  Can I not use a custom flashvar to pass to the player?

meta property="og:video" content="http://mediasuite.multicastmedia.com/templates/facebook.swf?mediaSuiteURL=http://player.multicastmedia.com/ws/get_vod_player_info/p_sfz538e8/api_f4d84551-2e85-103a-a1ba-00e08655b9fc/apiv_3.5/gft_0/sfz538e8.xml"

Any help will be great.

Thanks!